# Why won't Steam start after a recent update?

Tags: 12.10, steam

I'm running Steam for Linux (native, not Wine) on Ubuntu 12.10 32 bits. Since the last Steam update, it doesn't work anymore. Instead of starting, it pops a terminal claiming that it needs to install an additional package. Unfortunately, the operation doesn't work. Here's the output:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
    steam-launcher
[sudo] password for tvuillemin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package steam-launcher
Press return to continue:
```

My OS is up-to-date. I tried to reinstall Steam both from the Ubuntu Software Center and from the Steam website, but I got precisely the same error. I also looked for a repository with this package, but I didn't find anything relevant.

Any clue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: see [this github issue](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/1977). They solved and closed the issue 40 minutes ago. It can take some time until the fix gets in the ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your sources first:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then try again or search for `steam-launcher` in the Software Center for example.